# Vuetify.js: How do I change color of v-btn component when clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to change the color of a button when clicked. I have two buttons. When one button is clicked, it assigns variable "host", when the other button is clicked, it assigns variable "guest".

```html
<v-btn color="primary" fab large
 @click="type='host'">
   <v-icon>home</v-icon><br/>Host
</v-btn>

<v-btn color="secondary" fab large
 @click="type='guest'">
   <v-icon>person</v-icon><br/>Request
</v-btn>
```

I've tried the following:

1. colon shorthand

```html
<v-btn v-bind:style="{ color: type==='host' ? 'secondary' : 'primary' }>
<v-icon>home</v-icon>
HOST
</v-btn>

AND

<v-btn v-bind:color="{ type==='guest' ? 'secondary' : 'primary' }>   
<v-icon>person</v-icon><br/>
Request
</v-btn>
```

but neither works

2. `v-btn-toggle` doesn't do the job and doesn't have the styles we want (which is a circle)

I'm a newby in vue.js and don't know how to debug this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Color is not a CSS property it's a property of `v-btn` itself so you can pass in any JS expression you want. The following should probably work.

`<v-btn v-bind:color="type==='guest' ? 'secondary' : 'primary'>`.

Comment: I was missing the single quotes '_color_' . Thanks

Comment: Make sure you close the quotation mark (and you don't need the v-bind-prefix): <v-btn :color="type==='guest' ? 'secondary' : 'primary'">

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/mhw8rkeL/) for you. You should bind property color using v-bind:

```
<v-btn v-bind:color="type === 1 ? 'success' : 'error'">Success</v-btn>
```